# Are evolutionary algorithms calculated in polynomial time?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics, theoretical-biology

How complex are evolutionary algorithms? Also, what is the relationship between variational principles (Lagrangians, minima and maxima,) and evolutionary algorithms? Basically, how hard is it right now to construct an algorithm that reproduces what we see in the evolutionary history of life? Could you, in theory, use variational principles to reduce the complexity of evolutionary algorithms, and gain novel understanding of how evolution works in the process?

Comment: I think you need to clarify just what you're asking.  Evolutionary algorithms themselves tend to be quite simple, and run in pretty close to linear time.  The problem is that evaluating the fitness function can be very time-consuming.  One application I worked on involved solving a set of fairly complicated differential equations on a 3D volume, so O(n^3) - several seconds for each evaluation, microseconds to test the evaluation in the GA. I would guess that evaluating fitness functions for evolutionary biology would be more complicated still.

Comment: Yeah it is rather vague now that I look at it. Essentially, the question is about the possibility of using variational principles to *feasibly* create an algorithm which reconstructs *exactly* what we see in the evolutionary history of life, and, if we did that, how would it enrich our understanding of the intricacies of evolution. The philosophy behind it is that you can use variational principles to make everything *so much easier* in understanding evolution, so why aren't people doing it? Are they doing it? If you took the intrinsic variational principels of ecology, wow! Insight!

Comment: For instance, this article applies dynamic equations of motion derived from the principle of stationary action to ecology. We know there's an intimate relationship between ecological conditions and evolution now. If we can apply Hamilton's principle to ecology, and ecology directly impacts evolution, how can we use this approach to further understand evolution? Article link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030438009400046K

Comment: Your question is very broad a quite unclear. You ask four different questions (a post should always be restricted to a single question). `How complex are evolutionary algorithms?` 1) This question is broad and unclear 2) Evolutionary algorithms are a concept in computer science, not so much in biology, hence this specific question should not be asked on biology.SE. `Basically, how hard is it right now to construct an algorithm that reproduces what we see in the evolutionary history of life?` ...

Comment: ... Evolutionary algorithm, in general, don't aim at answering questions in evolutionary biology. Evolutionary algorithms are a type of optimization algorithms, used to solve a number of optimization problems, many of them are completely unrelated to biology. That being said, we do perform a lot of simulations of evolutionary processes. Aside obvious issues of ressources, simulating "evolutionary history of life" in general is quite of an impossible task as the process is quite chaotic....

Comment: ... It is like asking "can we simulate this specific wave?" without giving the starting conditions of the wave rather than asking "can we simulate wave-like processes?"

Comment: For all the reasons mentioned above, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: Well, to be fair its basically 2 questions, but sure. I don't see a conclusive or logical reason to believe evolution is random or "chaotic" though. There seems to be good evidence for it being a product of specific initial conditions in the environment, which can be modeled by an optimization function. Secondly, it is like asking if we can simulate this specific wave! That's the point! I'm asking if you can generate the "initial conditions" of that wave from the already known initial conditions of ecology.

Comment: @Liam Wasserman: Even if one accepts for the sake of argument that evolution is not random, the initial/ongoing conditions certainly are.  For example, suppose that the Chixulub asteroid happens to miss the Earth: then from that point on evolution takes an entirely different path.

Comment: The conservation of information implies that we can reconstruct an image of those types of events, so the randomness is purely epistemic/technological in nature. Nonetheless, I’ll admit a gentleman’s defeat: my question is just too broad.

Comment: @LiamWasserman You might underestimate the fantastic complexity of evolutionnary processes, with the feedback loops between evolution and ecology, geology, the details of how genotype affect phenotypes and the resulting fitness of an individual. Numerical simulations are very common (typically, in the form of of individual-based simulations) but only to investigate specific, clearly defined, questions and not to reproduce the entirety of the evolution of life on earth. (I am doing my PhD in computational evolutionary genetics and performs loads of individual-based simulations)

Comment: You're partially right. I am an ultra novice, if even that. But! If you found the equations of motion for ecological change, and had a dope evolutionary algorithm, you could in theory gain incredibly novel understanding of evolution. The arguments are sound. This is where variational principles would come in handy. Anyways, it was an interesting convo, thank you all.

Comment: This article is fascinating: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.4032.pdf

Comment: This question is off topic in Biology.SE because it is mostly about the computational algorithm. [scicomp.se] may be be better site for this question if other issues regarding general SE rules are addressed.